# getting List has no rows for assignment to SObject error on comparing parent location related to parent campaign

Tags: apex

```
@AuraEnabled public static List<MarketWrapper> getMarkets(string parentStoryIds){
    //public static List<MarketWrapper> getMarkets(Id CampaignId){
    List<CM_Market_Execution__c> marketExecutionList = new List<CM_Market_Execution__c>();
    Map<String,String> MarketParentMap = new Map<String,String>();//set Child and Parent location
    List<MarketWrapper> marketList = new List<MarketWrapper>();
    marketExecutionList = CM_MarketExecutionModel.queryMarketExecutions( 
        new List<String>{   'id',
                            'CM_Child_Location__c',
                            'CM_Child_Story_Owner__c',
                            'CM_Parent_Location__c'} );
    Campaign pcmp = [SELECT Id, CM_Location__c FROM Campaign WHERE Id=:parentStoryIds ];
    for(CM_Market_Execution__c currentMarket : marketExecutionList){
        if(pcmp.CM_Location__c  == currentMarket.CM_Parent_Location__c){
            MarketWrapper marketWrapperObj = new MarketWrapper();
            marketWrapperObj.label = currentMarket.CM_Child_Location__c; // Select the Label
            marketWrapperObj.value = currentMarket.CM_Child_Location__c; // Select the Value
            marketList.add(marketWrapperObj);
        }
    }
    return marketList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parentStoryIds` is either null, not a Campaign record ID, or the user does not have access to the record. There's a few recommended ways to handle this situation, but for an @AuraEnabled error, you should probably just throw an AuraHandledException to signal an error.

```
Campaign pcmp;
try {
  pcmp = [SELECT Id, CM_Location__c FROM Campaign WHERE Id=:parentStoryIds ];
} catch(QueryException e) {
  throw new AuraHandledException('Missing or invalid Campaign ID.');
}
```

Note that this probably means you have a bug somewhere else in your code, so you'll need to review the client-side code to debug this problem.